# iOS getting User's Facebook ID & friends List with Profile picture URL of Friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user id from Facebook and Friend list, with friends id & profile picture URL of friends. I've two code samples, first is

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields": @"name, id, picture"};
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

this returns friend list with profile picture URL of friends too, but does not return user's own Facebook id. Second is

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,friends, picture"}]
```

This returns user's Facebook id, friend list but doesn't return profile picture URL of friends. Can you help me out here, how can I get both things in one call ?

Comment: Can you show me the permission what are the permission you gave

Comment: @Bhupat Bheda Permissions are [@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]

Comment: Possible using Field Expansion, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: Yes it return the Facebook ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use below code snippet:

```
-(void)getFacebookFriednData{

    FBSDKLoginManager *fbSdkLoginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [fbSdkLoginManager logOut];    
    [fbSdkLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if (!result.isCancelled) {
                NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields":@"id,name,email,picture,friends"};
                FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                              initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                              parameters:params
                                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                [SVProgressHUD show];
                [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                    if (!error) {

                       NSLog(@"%@",result); // here u get all require data              
                    }
                }];
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);  ?/ Handle Error Here.
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3

This is how I get this info for friends who are using my app

```
if ((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){

    if let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "email, name, gender, picture"] ) {
         request.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

             if (error == nil){
                  guard let userInfo = result as? [String: Any] else { return } //handle the error
                  print("data------:\(userInfo)")
             } else {

                  //handle any errors

             }
        }
    }
}
```

The userInfo has the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
NSString *pictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID];
```

Comment: in my question I wrote that solution 1 is giving me picture, but it does return me user's own id, name, picture etc. I want user id and his friend's user ids.

Comment: In your question you wrote "This returns user's Facebook id, friend list but doesn't return profile picture URL of friends."

Comment: yeah, both of these solutions are working fine but I want both of these outputs in one query. I want user's own id, friends id, friends profile pic url, friends name.